# Some online tool or automation plugin for SublimeText for generating Sphinx RST tables

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am using Sphinx for documentation.

I would like to easily genearate based e.g on CSV file or copy-paste text the table like shown here: [reStructuredText Tables](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#tables).

```
+------------------------+------------+----------+----------+
| Header row, column 1   | Header 2   | Header 3 | Header 4 |
| (header rows optional) |            |          |          |
+========================+============+==========+==========+
| body row 1, column 1   | column 2   | column 3 | column 4 |
+------------------------+------------+----------+----------+
| body row 2             | ...        | ...      |          |
+------------------------+------------+----------+----------+
```

Which SublimeText plugin can I use for it or maybe there exists some online tool?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

All right I found something like this http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables

It creates eaxctly what I wanted and you can easily import CSV file, or just copy-paste.

Answer (score 19):

Using a CSV list to define a table is possible in ReST without any extra tools (many people don't know that though, including me until recently). You can link to a file or URL as resource, or just provide the text:

```
.. csv-table:: Frozen Delights!
   :header: "Treat", "Quantity", "Description"
   :widths: 15, 10, 30

   "Albatross", 2.99, "On a stick!"
   "Crunchy Frog", 1.49, "If we took the bones out, it wouldn't be
   crunchy, now would it?"
   "Gannet Ripple", 1.99, "On a stick!"
```

Creates this table:

[image: result of CSV table in restructuredText]

Documentation can be found here: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#id4

Comment: List Table (`.. list-table::`) is another alternative https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#list-table

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the build-in sphinx [List Table](https://rest-sphinx-memo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ReST.html#list-table)

> A list-table (ref) is a two level list, where the first level is a row and the second one a column list. The number of column must be uniform (no column span) but cell may contain structured markup.

```
.. list-table:: Weather forecast
   :header-rows: 1
   :widths: 7 7 7 7 60
   :stub-columns: 1

   *  -  Day
      -  Min Temp
      -  Max Temp
      -
      -  Summary
   *  -  Monday
      -  11C
      -  22C
      -  .. image:: _static/sunny.svg
            :width: 30
      -  A clear day with lots of sunshine.
         However, the strong breeze will bring
         down the temperatures.
   *  -  Tuesday
      -  9C
      -  10C
   ...
```

which leads to this table:

[image: List Table Example]

Further [documentation](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#list-table)